# ifelse() not working in Legend R

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering why `ifelse()` in my `legend()` below doesn't work as it should? I get the following error:

`**Error in rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'**`

Here is my **R code:**

```
Gi <- 2      
plot(1:10,ty="n")  

legend("topright",
  legend=ifelse(Gi>1,      ## ! ifelse() Not Working HERE ! ##
    bquote(paste("Evidence favors A: ",bold('CT'[10]),
                " = ", .(round(Gi,3)))),
    bquote(paste("Evidence favors B: ",bold('CT'[01]),
                " = ", .(round(1/Gi,3))))),
  pch = " ",cex=1.5, bty="n", inset=c(.005,-.05))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not really sure what the bquote() function does for you, but I changed your code a little and got the legend to appear on your plot.

This is the code, let me know if you think it is correct.

```
Gi <- 2      
plot(1:10,ty="n")  

l <- ifelse(Gi>1, paste0("Evidence favors A: ",'CT[10]'," = ", (round(Gi,3))),
       paste0("Evidence favors B: ",'CT[01]'," = ",(round(1/Gi,3))))

legend("topright", legend=l, pch = " ",cex=1.5, bty="n", inset=c(.005,-.05))
```

Comment: Dinesh, thanks, But this doesn't do it, for `bquote()` please check `?bquote()`, here it ensures that `round()` and `CT[10]` BOTH work correctly. Also I guess there is a bug in your code.

Comment: What do you think is the bug? Also, I did check bquote(), it was the reason you had the error. Bquote evaluates the arguments that you provide as a language object, paste() returns a string. For a legend, a string works better.

Comment: Dear Dinesh, thanks for your update. First, your code doesn't allow subscript in `'CT'[10]` to show correctly and also has skipped the **bolding**. Second, change the `Gi` to `.25` to find the bug, it is the extra `.` in the second piece of your code.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to provide both alternative legend versions in an `if(){} else(){}` format:

```
Gi <- 2      
plot(1:10,ty="n")  

if(Gi>1){
 legend("topright",
  legend = bquote(paste("Evidence favors A: ",bold('CT'[10]),
                " = ", .(round(Gi,3)))),
  pch = " ",cex=1.5, bty="n", inset=c(.005,-.05))
} else {
 legend("topright",
  legend = bquote(paste("Evidence favors B: ",bold('CT'[01]),
                " = ", .(round(1/Gi,3))))),
  pch = " ",cex=1.5, bty="n", inset=c(.005,-.05))
}
```